# How to scale and add watermark (overlay) in one command?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

i want to encode video with watermark at once. but I am confused how to unify the video command and its watermark

command encode video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -tune psnr -refs 3 -c: v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 33 -vf scale = 640x360 videoencode.mp4
pause
```

and this is the watermark command

```
ffmpeg -i videoencode.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay = 10: 10" videofull.mp4
```

so how to unify in 1 command only? I am confused. i do not want to do 2 times encode video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying the scaling to the input, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:360[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=10:10" -tune psnr -refs 3 -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 33 videofull.mp4
```

Check `videofull.mp4` details using:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams videofull.mp4
```

Comment: very good :D work

Comment: Happy that it helped :)